# Развертывание системы на tmpfs

Tags: tmpfs, ubuntu, ram, linux

Есть рабочая виртуалка, которая безбожно тупит (на хосте стоит винда, от которой по ряду причин не откажусь и, скорее всего, никогда не поставлю линукс в параллель), при этом есть ядреный воз неиспользуемой оперативки, которую грех не использовать до того момента, пока не докуплю SSD специально под это дело. Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты автоматического развертывания всей системы/отдельных сервисов с диска в оперативке, репликации мускуля на оперативку без пары вечеров с консольным напильником? В идеале мне нужно просто ускорить веб-сервер, т.е. тупо перенести все файлы проектов на рамдиск в начале работы, вернуть их на место в конце, и каким-то образом проделать аналогичную работу с mysql/pgsql, высшим пилотажем было бы, чтобы у проектов даже настройки подключения не менялись.

p.s. Да, я пока ничего не профилировал, возможно затык даже не в фс. Но вордпрессу, думаю, это все равно понравится.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, а кэш уже не работает? Настройте кэширование, можно ещё запрефетчить  в кэш особо нужные куски (таром, например, "сархивировать" в /dev/null   (tar -c /var/lib/mysql/ >/dev/null))

Ещё - если у вас виртуалка, то какой "конец работы"? Сэйвите состояние, и всё.

Comment: @eicto, я честно развернул ее прямо перед тем, как начался бешеный вал работы, поэтому даже не пробовал сохранять стейт, и с кэшем не возялся тоже - только смонтировал tmp в tmpfs. Ну и мне спокойней будет, если все это с какой-то периодичностью все-таки будет сохраняться на диск, я пару раз уже гробил собственные наработки из-за того, что недостаточно часто коммиттился, и лучше лишний раз перестрахуюсь, чем еще раз спущусь на самое дно фрустрации.